# uncaught typeError:cannot set property 'src' of null:file:///android_asset/www/cordova.js;312

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, cordova, ionic-framework

I am new to ionic and trying to integrate Google-Plus in my application.
Every thing is working fine but at last step of the process i am getting above mentioned error.I have no idea to solve this error i googled but unable to solve it, so finally i am here to seek your help

here is my app.js file :-

```html
var app = angular.module('ionicApp', [ 'ionic' ])

app.config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {

 $stateProvider.state('app', {
  url : '/app',
  abstract : true,
  templateUrl : 'templates/menu.html',
 })

 .state('login', {
  url : "/login",
  templateUrl : "templates/login.html",
  controller : "LoginCtrl"
 })

 .state('app.home', {
  url : '/home',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/home.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.products', {
  url : '/products',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/products.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.products-details', {
  url : '/products-details',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/products-details.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.cart', {
  url : '/cart',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/cart.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.checkout', {
  url : '/checkout',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/checkout.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.register', {
  url : '/register',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/register.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.categories', {
  url : '/categories',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/categories.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.search', {
  url : '/search',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/search.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.profile', {
  url : '/profile',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/profile.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.change-pass', {
  url : '/change-pass',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/change-pass.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.profile-page', {
  url : '/profile-page',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/profile-page.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.myorders', {
  url : '/myorders',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/myorders.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.delivery', {
  url : '/delivery',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/delivery.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.placeorder', {
  url : '/placeorder',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/placeorder.html'

   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.splash', {
  url : '/splash',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/splash.html'
   }
  }
 })

 .state('app.paymethod', {
  url : '/paymethod',
  views : {
   'menuContent' : {
    templateUrl : 'templates/paymethod.html'
   }
  }
 })

 $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/login");
});

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $state, $ionicSideMenuDelegate) {

 $scope.create = function() {
  $state.go('app.category');
 };
 $scope.close = function() {
  $state.go('app.products');
 };

 // categories accordian
 $scope.groups = [];
 for ( var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
  $scope.groups[i] = {
   name : i,
   items : []
  };
  for ( var j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
   $scope.groups[i].items.push(i + '-' + j);
  }
 }

 /*
  * if given group is the selected group, deselect it else, select the given
  * group
  */
 $scope.toggleGroup = function(group) {
  if ($scope.isGroupShown(group)) {
   $scope.shownGroup = null;
  } else {
   $scope.shownGroup = group;
  }
 };
 $scope.isGroupShown = function(group) {
  return $scope.shownGroup === group;
 };

});
```

here is my controllers.js file :-

```html
app
  .controller(
    'LoginCtrl',
    function($scope, $stateParams) {
     $scope.login = function() {
      window.plugins.googleplus
        .login(
          {},
          function(obj) {
           document.querySelector("#image").src = obj.imageUrl;
           document.querySelector("#image").style.visibility = 'visible';
           document.querySelector("#feedback").innerHTML = "Hi, "
             + obj.displayName
             + ", "
             + obj.email;
          },
          function(msg) {
           document.querySelector("#feedback").innerHTML = "error: "
             + msg;
          });
     }
     window.onerror = function(what, line, file) {
      alert(what + '; ' + line + '; ' + file);
     };
     function handleOpenURL(url) {
      document.querySelector("#feedback").innerHTML = "App was opened by URL: "
        + url;
     }
    });
```

here is my config.xml

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<widget xmlns:cdv="http://cordova.apache.org/ns/1.0"
    xmlns:gap="http://phonegap.com/ns/1.0"
    id="com.ionicframework.ecommerce785960"
    version="0.0.1"
    xmlns="http://www.w3.org/ns/widgets" >

    <name>
e-commerce
    </name>

    <description>
        An Ionic Framework and Cordova project.
    </description>

    <author
        email="hi@ionicframework"
        href="http://ionicframework.com/" >
      Ionic Framework Team
    </author>

    <content src="index.html" />

    <access origin="*" />

    <preference
        name="webviewbounce"
        value="false" />

    <preference
        name="UIWebViewBounce"
        value="false" />

    <preference
        name="DisallowOverscroll"
        value="true" />

    <preference
        name="android-minSdkVersion"
        value="16" />

    <preference
        name="BackupWebStorage"
        value="none" />

    <preference
        name="SplashScreen"
        value="screen" />

    <preference
        name="SplashScreenDelay"
        value="3000" />

    <feature name="StatusBar" >

        <param
            name="ios-package"
            onload="true"
            value="CDVStatusBar" />
    </feature>

    <platform name="android" >

        <icon
            density="ldpi"
            src="resources/android/icon/drawable-ldpi-icon.png" />

        <icon
            density="mdpi"
            src="resources/android/icon/drawable-mdpi-icon.png" />

        <icon
            density="hdpi"
            src="resources/android/icon/drawable-hdpi-icon.png" />

        <icon
            density="xhdpi"
            src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xhdpi-icon.png" />

        <icon
            density="xxhdpi"
            src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxhdpi-icon.png" />

        <icon
            density="xxxhdpi"
            src="resources/android/icon/drawable-xxxhdpi-icon.png" />

        <splash
            density="land-ldpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-ldpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="land-mdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-mdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="land-hdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-hdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="land-xhdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xhdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="land-xxhdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxhdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="land-xxxhdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-land-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="port-ldpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-ldpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="port-mdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-mdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="port-hdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-hdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="port-xhdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xhdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="port-xxhdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxhdpi-screen.png" />

        <splash
            density="port-xxxhdpi"
            src="resources/android/splash/drawable-port-xxxhdpi-screen.png" />
    </platform>

    <gap:plugin
        name="cordova-plugin-googleplus"
        source="npm" >

        <param
            name="REVERSED_CLIENT_ID"
            value="974087359524-ta7cv0tivlt16iladpoeud75f2g5so9i.apps.googleusercontent.com" />
    </gap:plugin>

</widget>
```

And here is my index.html :-

```html
<script src="lib/ionic/js/ionic.bundle.js"></script>
<!-- cordova script (this will be a 404 during development) -->
<script src="cordova.js"></script>
<!-- your app's js -->
<script src="js/app.js"></script>
<script src="js/controllers.js"></script>

</head>
<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">

 <ion-nav-view></ion-nav-view>

</body>
```

Steps followed by me to integrate google plus in my app :-

https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/cordova-plugin-googleplus/blob/master/demo/index.html

Any help will be appreciated. 
Thanks.

Comment: Does it work in a web browser?

Comment: Hey, Thanks for your reply but i think plugins never work with browser..so i tested it on device , the whole process goes fine but at last alert pops up with this error.

Comment: It seems "document.querySelector("#image").src" is your problem? That's where you're referencing "src" - It might not be plugin related. That's why I was asking if it works in the browser.

Comment: On button click no actions seems to get performed on browser but on device it ask me to add account.

Comment: Which template file has the "#image" element? Can you share the HTML?